# Laravel: display file from cloud storage in the browser

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

This snippet from the Laravel docs, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-responses, seems to be just what I need:

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

The problem is that my file is stored on an S3 disk, and I can't seem to reference it properly.

I tried using `Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($myPath);` to get the fully qualified file name.  It just returned the value of `$myPath` though.

I then tried to get the url using `Storage::disk('s3')->url($myPath);`  The URL looks fine however Symphony says it does not exist.  When I check with `Storage::disk('s3')->exists($myPath);` however, it returns `true`.

How do I go about displaying a file from cloud storage directly in the user's browser?

EDIT:

More details below:

- To save the item in the first instance I am using `$map->storeAs('/my/path/maps/filename.pdf', ['disk' => 's3']);`
- The output of `url()` is "https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my.domain.com/my/path/maps/filename.pdf"
- When I cut-and-past the url in a browser address bar, it loads no problem
- It seems to me that the `response()->file()` method does not accept a URL parameter.  Is that the case?

Question - does the file need to be publicly available?  (It currently is, but I would prefer to make it private).

Answer (score 1):

The following should be enough:

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
```

I don't have a working example set up, but from memory `$filename` should be the same as what you originally placed in the `->put()` method. So when you say `$mypath` in your question, hopefully that isn't already prefixing stuff like your s3 instance.

If this isn't the case, can you edit the question to include the result of `->url()` and an example of your put() call and $path.

Looking at the edit, I think I understand what you are trying to do, which has been solved here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/file-response-from-s3

Comment: Your second dot point, "the output of url()" looks correct.. How are you using the output of url()? What do you expect the response to return?